# Why can't I connect to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I initially installed SQL Server 2008 R2 with Windows authentication mode and have successfully changed it to mixed mode (per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx).

After this I am able to log in to my SQL Server with SQL Server authentication. But from another computer which is on my network, I am not able to connect my server.

Comment: After all that, your problem is that the agent isn't started? talk about a long story and title going nowhere...

Comment: I don't think it matters if SQL Server Agent is running, have you enabled TCP/IP Connections? You really should cut all the irrelevant material out of your question and rename your question. Plus this should probably be moved to db admins

Comment: Your SQL Server Browser service is maybe not running. See my checklist in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6001023/44522

Comment: It would be very helpful if you explain what "not able to connect" means. Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Did you check the state in the SQL Server error log?

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons SQL Server 2008 no longer opens TCP port 1433 upon installation.  You will need to create a firewall rule that allows communication over TCP port 1433 (and UDP port 1434 if you wish to use the browser service) to allow applications to communicate with SQL Server.

Comment: Does this apply to `SQL Server 2008 R2 Express` version also?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think that the problem is with your SQL Server Agent, as this is just to perform tasks related to Backup, Replication ... etc.

I have written an article which has an idea of what your problem could be:

[Cannot Login to SQL Server from Network](http://www.it-archives.com/Articles/CannotLogintoSQLServerFromNetwork.aspx)